# how to control the Activity method flow till non activity class perform network operation

Tags: java, android, methods, control-flow

i have one method in activity in which some operations are performed from non activity class. i want to know when the non activity class network operation are completed so that i can call that method again. but when i call non activity class then the method goes to at the end.

here is my code

```
public void somemethod(){
            .
            .
            .
            .               
if (condition) {

    new RegenerateToken().generate(DriverActivity.this); // calling non activity class which perform some network operation

    //here i want to know that non activity class has performed the network operation so i can call this method again

    }       
            .
            .
            .
log.d("method","ending");
}
```

non activity class

```
public class RegenerateToken {
    public void generate(Context context) {
    
    ExecuteServerReq executeServerReq = new ExecuteServerReq(context, client, Utilz.URL + "/authenticate", params, true, true);
    executeServerReq.execute();
    executeServerReq.getResponse = new ExecuteServerReq.GetResponse() {
    
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String objects) {
      Utilz.printLog("RegenerateTokenresponse", objects);
    }
    };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement an interface to get the callback

```
public class RegenerateToken {

public interface Callback {
    public void onResponce(String data);
}

public void generate(Context context,final Callback callBack) {
    ExecuteServerReq executeServerReq = new ExecuteServerReq(context, client, Utilz.URL + "/authenticate", params, true, true);
    executeServerReq.execute();
    executeServerReq.getResponse = new ExecuteServerReq.GetResponse() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String objects) {
        Utilz.printLog("RegenerateTokenresponse", objects);
        callBack.onResponce(objects);
    }};
}
}
```

Callback implementation

```
if(condition) {
    new RegenerateToken().generate(DriverActivity.this, new Callback() {  
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String objects) { //your data do ur processing
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LocalBroacastManager to send and receive information within your app

```
public class RegenerateToken {

    public void generate(Context context) {
    //your code
        executeServerReq.getResponse = new ExecuteServerReq.GetResponse() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String objects) {
                Utilz.printLog("RegenerateTokenresponse", objects);
                Intent intent = new Intent("Respone");
                if(expected responce){    
                    intent.putExtra("result", "Successful");
                }
                else{
                    intent.putExtra("result", "UnSuccessful");     
                }
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(iIntent);

            }
        };
    }
}
```

And at your Activity register and define a receiver for your Local Broadcast

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    //Register the custom Broadcast "Response"

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
    new IntentFilter("Response"));
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "Response" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver myMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String response= intent.getStringExtra("result");
    if(response.equals("Successful")){
        //on successful execution
        // call your method again or do whatever you wish
    }else{
        //on otherwise            
    }
  }
};
```